# YouTube Python Bot With Selenium How to Wait?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

Lately, i have been doing a YouTube bot that uploads automatically, the bot is pretty much done.
The bot uploads the video, writes the title, description, click next, next again, and again, at the finale step it chooses public, and then it publishes the bot.

At the last step, i want the bot to wait until the upload, processing and checking processes finishes, my idea is to stop the script till it located "Checks complete. No issues found." text.

I have been trying this syntax, but for some reason, it doesn't function:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[2]/div/div[1]/ytcp-video-upload-progress/span', "Checks complete. No issues found."))
```

I think that this lign of code is suppose to wait for the "Checks complete. No issues found." text to appear in the Xpath that i gave, and then ready code should be resumed!

Either i have a problem with the XPATH or something else that i don't know exactly, if anyone could help with anything i would really appreciate it!

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials

Comment: this question needs code.